# How to Pass an object when navigating to a new view in PRISM 4

Tags: wpf, navigation, prism

I am working on a PRISM application where we drill down into the data (to get more details). 
In my implementation I have a nested MVVM and when I navigate down the tree I would like to pass a model to a my newly created view.

As far as I know, currently PRISM allows to pass strings, but doesn't allow to pass objects. I would like to know what are the ways of overcoming this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i usually use a service where i register the objects i want to be passed with a guid. these get stored in a hashtable and when navigating in prism i pass the guid as a parameter which can then be used to retrieve the object.

hope this makes sense to you!

Comment: That makes sense. That's a shame PRISM doesn't support passing object during navigation it would make life so much easier.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom methods to pass on the objects using the NavigationContext.

First derive the viewmodel from INavigationAware interface -

```
 public class MyViewModel : INavigationAware
 { ...
```

You can then implement OnNavigatedFrom and set the object you want to pass as navigation context as follows -

```
void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
     SharedData data = new SharedData();
     ...
     navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.Context = data;
}
```

and when you want to receive the data, add the following piece of code in the second view model -

```
void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    if (navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.Context != null)
    {
                if (navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.Context is SharedData)
                {
                    SharedData data = (SharedData)navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.Context;
                    ...
                }
    }
}
```

ps. mark this as answer if this helps.

Comment: OnNavigatedFrom is only working if your a navigation to a view in the same region. If you are in another region you can do this:  _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].Context = new List<DataItem> { new DataItem() }; and then call RequestNavigate

Answer (score 2):

PRISM supports supplying parameters:

```
var para = new NavigationParameters { { "SearchResult", result } };
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(ShellRegions.DockedRight, typeof(UI.SearchResultView).FullName, OnNavigationCompleted, para);
```

and implement the INavigationAware interface on your View, ViewModel or both.

you can also find details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx