# How to improve the Pass an object when navigating to a new view in PRISM 4

Tags: c#, wpf, module, navigation, prism

I'm using Prism with IoC. The problem is to pass an object (like collections) through navigation. I was watching this post: [How to Pass an object when navigating to a new view in PRISM 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624903/how-to-pass-an-object-when-navigating-to-a-new-view-in-prism-4)

And this is the solution

I extract the hash code of the object and save it in a `Dictionary`, with the hash code as the key and the object as the value of the pair.

Then, I attach the hash code to the `UriQuery`.

After, I only have to get the hash code that comes from the Uri on the target view and use it to request the original object from the `Dictionary`.

Some example code:

Parameter repository class:

```
public class Parameters
{
    private static Dictionary<int, object> paramList =
        new Dictionary<int, object>();

    public static void save(int hash, object value)
    {
        if (!paramList.ContainsKey(hash))
            paramList.Add(hash, value);
    }

    public static object request(int hash)
    {
        return ((KeyValuePair<int, object>)paramList.
                    Where(x => x.Key == hash).FirstOrDefault()).Value;
    }
}
```

The caller code:

```
UriQuery q = null;
Customer customer = new Customer();
q = new UriQuery();
Parameters.save(customer.GetHashCode(), customer);
q.Add("hash", customer.GetHashCode().ToString());

Uri viewUri = new Uri("MyView" + q.ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(region, viewUri);
```

The target view code:

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl, INavigationAware
{
// some hidden code

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        int hash = int.Parse(navigationContext.Parameters["hash"]);
        Customer cust = (Customer)Parameters.request(hash);
    }
}
```

That's it.

I'm not sure if this solution is the best to pass objects. I guess this maybe would be a service. Is a good way to do this or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I posted an easier way. Mentioning it here for reference -

I would use the OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom methods to pass on the objects using the NavigationContext.

First derive the viewmodel from INavigationAware interface -

```
 public class MyViewModel : INavigationAware
 { ...
```

You can then implement OnNavigatedFrom and set the object you want to pass as navigation context as follows -

```
void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
     SharedData data = new SharedData();
     ...
     navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.Context = data;
}
```

and when you want to receive the data, add the following piece of code in the second view model -

```
void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    if (navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.Context != null)
    {
        if (navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.Context is SharedData)
        {
             SharedData data = (SharedData)navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.Context;
              ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just started using Prism and this is one of the first limitations I ran into.  I solved it a different way.  I first created a class that inherits from Uri and implements IDictionary (plus some generic methods for easier access)

```
public class NavigationUri : Uri, IDictionary<Type, object>
{
    private IDictionary<Type, object> _internalDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public NavigationUri(string uriString) : base(uriString, UriKind.Relative)
    {
    }
    public NavigationUri(string uriString, UriKind uriKind) :  base(uriString, uriKind)
    {
    }

    public void Add<T>(T value)
    {
        Add(typeof(T), value);
    }

    public void Add(Type key, object value)
    {
        _internalDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey<T>()
    {
        return ContainsKey(typeof (T));
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(Type key)
    {
        return _internalDictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<Type> Keys
    {
        get { return _internalDictionary.Keys; }
    }

    public bool Remove<T>()
    {
        return Remove(typeof (T));
    }

    public bool Remove(Type key)
    {
        return _internalDictionary.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(out object value)
    {
        return TryGetValue(typeof (T), out value);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(Type key, out object value)
    {
        return _internalDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<object> Values
    {
        get { return _internalDictionary.Values; }
    }

    public object this[Type key]
    {
        get { return _internalDictionary[key]; }
        set { _internalDictionary[key] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<Type, object> item)
    {
        _internalDictionary.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _internalDictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<Type, object> item)
    {
        return _internalDictionary.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<Type, object>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _internalDictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _internalDictionary.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return _internalDictionary.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<Type, object> item)
    {
        return _internalDictionary.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<Type, object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _internalDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _internalDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then I created a class that inherits from RegionNavigationContentLoader.  On GetContractFromNavigationContext I store the passed in Uri so I can access it in the CreateNewRegionItem method.  In that method I check to see if the Uri is the NavigationUri and if so I loop though adding all the dependency injection overrides.  I'm using Unity but I assume the code could easy be converted to another IOC container.

```
public class BaseRegionNavigationContentLoader : RegionNavigationContentLoader
{
    private Uri _uri;
    private IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;
    private IUnityContainer _unityContainer;

    public BaseRegionNavigationContentLoader(IServiceLocator serviceLocator, IUnityContainer unityContainer) : base(serviceLocator)
    {
        _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
        _unityContainer = unityContainer;
    }

    protected override string GetContractFromNavigationContext(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        _uri = navigationContext.Uri;
        return base.GetContractFromNavigationContext(navigationContext);
    }

    protected override object CreateNewRegionItem(string candidateTargetContract)
    {
        object instance;
        try
        {
            var uri = _uri as NavigationUri;
            if (uri == null)
            {
                instance = _serviceLocator.GetInstance<object>(candidateTargetContract);
            }
            else
            {
                // Create injection overrides for all the types in the uri
                var depoverride = new DependencyOverrides();
                foreach (var supplant in uri)
                {
                    depoverride.Add(supplant.Key, supplant.Value);
                }

                instance = _unityContainer.Resolve<object>(candidateTargetContract, depoverride);
            }

        }
        catch (ActivationException exception)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "CannotCreateNavigationTarget", new object[] { candidateTargetContract }), exception);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now in the prism Bootstrapper you need to register the BaseRegionNavigationContentLoader as IRegionNavigationContentLoader in the ConfigureServiceLocator method.  **Make sure you mark it as TransientLifetimeManager so it gets newed up each time**.  The default registration for IRegionNavigationContentLoader is container controlled which makes it act like a singleton but we need a new one each time since we need to pass the uri from one method to the next in a property.

Now I can wright code like the following and still use constructor injection.

```
var uri = new NavigationUri("MessageBoxView");
uri.Add(messageBoxEventArgs);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, uri);
```

Comment: This is a supersolution, maybe prism 4.2 has solved this problem the same way, now that the finally have support for passing objects. But I think that you have only fixed the problem 90% (-: Is the a way to avoid casting the NavigationContext.Uri to NavigationUri each time you want to retrieve the params. var values = ((NavigationUri)navigationContext.Uri).Values;

Comment: Guess I don't totally understand your question.  In our application the view creates the viewmodel.  So if I have a MsgBoxView and in it's constructor it creates the MsgBoxVM and the MsgBoxVM constructor takes in another class, lets call that class MsgBoxOptions. I would create a var uri = new NavigationUri("MsgBoxView");   If I created the MsgBoxOptions already and have that in a variable called msgBoxOptions I would then do uri.Add(msgBoxOptions).  The in the constructor of the viewmodel the MsgBoxOptions parameter would be filled in with the same obj.

Comment: One of the enhancements we did was to also save the UriQuery when we save the Uri in the BaseRegionNavigationContentLoader and auto add that to the NavigationUri.  So if I want the UriQuery I can get access to it in the constructor by just adding it as a parameter in the view model.  I like this way better than catching it in the navigation events that are defined.  Is that what you are looking for?  If so I can update the code to be more what we have now.